# Can I setup a text only session and a GUI session at once?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, gui, tui

I am yet on my legendary Lenovo T400 laptop which has the built in LCD display and a VGA connector which allow me to have an external monitor attached to my laptop and share different sceneries for what is about the display arrangement.

The graphics card as showin in `lspci | grep "Graphics"` shows the next in a terminal:

```
geppettvs@T400:~$ lspci | grep "Graphics"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

For local/remote/ssh coding/testing purposes, I would like to have a terminal (text only mode) in the builtin LCD and a GUI in the external monitor.

I have tried going into a text only session and starting the X via `startx i3` (I am using i3wm for my graphic user interface) and I have also tried going in the GUI session and entering the thext mode via <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>~<kbd>F7</kbd> after which I try to start the X session but it throws me back to a GUI only mode session.

Both attempts are resulting in the same scenery: delivering a one-instance GUI or TUI mode.

I already have Guake running, which allows me to hit a key combo in order to invoke guake over any monitor but what I do need is to run a real TTY terminal in a monitor while I have another instance (it can be a different instance) of a session in a different monitor.

Is it there a way to accomplish what I wish?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not run the full DE with extended desktop on the second screen, and then run a maximized terminal window on the other screen?  This would accomplish the same effect.  Even though the terminal window is being run in a GUI, it can still be full screen and behave the same way.

Comment: I already have Guake running, which allows me to hit a key combo in order to invoke guake over any monitor but what I do need is to run a real TTY terminal in a monitor while I have another instance (it can be a different instance) of a session in a different monitor. Anyway, thank you for pointing that as a solution.